# Telnet: localhost on Windows 7 will not connect to localhost

Tags: node.js, localhost, telnet

I am running a simple Node.JS server with the code:

```
require('http').createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8' });
  res.end('<h1>Hi there world</h1>');
}).listen(3000);
```

It works as expected. When I type "http://localhost:3000" the header "Hi there world" appears.

When I use telnet however:

```
telnet localhost 3000
```

I only get the message:

```
Connecting To localhost...
```

Firewall is switched off. Telnet connects to external hosts without any problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I'd guess your node.js server is waiting for you to issue a GET request.
When it is waiting after the message `Connecting to Localhost...`.

The telnet client doesn't visually indicate that it is connected. Just write your request and it should get entered.

Put your **GET** request in:

```
GET / HTTP 1.1
```

Comment: How should i put these parameters in? It just says it is connecting, and does not look like ready to take input. When I press a couple of keys it stops to try, and is not connected to localhost.

Comment: The telnet window never looks ready to take input ;), but if you enter characters, does it get echoed on the cmd window?

Comment: It does something strange. The characters appear behind the text previously entered in the lines above. Kind of difficult to figure out what is going on.

Comment: But even so, when I manage to type in `sen GET / HTTP 1.1` I get `Not connected.`